I can't connect dbt to two databases | cross-database
I have a problem regarding DBT. I created some tables in POSTGRESQL:
select * from libraria.main.usuario u;
select * from libraria.main.endereco and ;
select * from libraria.main.telefone t;
select * from libraria.main.livro l;
select * from libraria.main.emprestimo and ;
And I now want to create stagings for these tables in DBT, but the problem is that I want DBT to take the table that is in the LIVRARIA database and create the staging in the DBT_DEV database.
But I tried to configure it but it insists on putting the staging in the LIVRARIA database.
schema
dbt_project
staging_livraria_usuario
error

Unfortunately, due to postgresql limitation there is no straightforward way to use different databases.
Potential solutions are:

Move source tables into your analytics/staging database
Use some workaround with FDW or dblink (details are in this GitHub issue)


my profiles.yml file is configured this way:
dbt_models_project:
target: dev
outputs:
dev:
type: postgres
host: localhost
user: #####
pass: ####
port: 5432
dbname: dbt_dev
schema: main

Interesting, and still dbt creates tables in libraria database instead of dbt_dev? Does dbt throw any error? Have you tried point to your profiels file explicitly by --profiles-dir?

This is the error I'm having:
Database Error in model staging_livraria_usuario (models\staging\livraria\staging_livraria_usuario.sql)
cross-database references are not implemented: "livraria.main.usuario"
LINE 10: select * from livraria.main.usuario

Could you edit your question and add there code of the staging_livraria_usario.sql and the text of the error?

I just inserted the images of the error and the profiles.yml, schema.yml, dbt_project.yml and staging scripts

Oh, I see now. Thanks for sharing. I'd encourage you to delete profiles image from your question as it contains credentials. But your problem is a limitation of postgresql, sorry for the initial confusion with my answer. Here is a discussion about this problem and they have some tricky workarounds: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/2182
